# Jenkins shared library get version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I have got shared library loaded with `@Library('libName')` annotation in jenkinsfiles. How to get knowledge (in the code of the pipeline) which version has been loaded? How to distinguish if the library has been loaded using:
`@Library('libName')`,  `@Library('libName@master')` or  `@Library('libName@superBranch')`?
Regards, Dawid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me on Jenkins 2.318 and returns the branch name, at least inside the library:

`env."library.LIBNAME.version"`

Where `LIBNAME` is the name of your library, so in your example:

`echo "library version: ${env."library.libName.version"}"`

Would print e.g. `master` or `superBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar below.

```
@Library('MyLibrary@test') _
node('master') {

    dir( "${WORKSPACE}@libs/MyLibrary") {
        //This is the path library.
        //Run any command to get branch name
    }
}
```

Important point: If you run this job concurrently, library directory names will be something like this `MyLibrary@2` depending on the build number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not easy, but this is what my project does. We use git tags but its essentially the same concept. However because we use a convention, we can differentiate. (Jenkins shared checkouts check the @'whatever' as a branch first and then a tag revision).

This is under the hood stuff, so no guarantee it will stay the same during jenkins development.

The wrapper function essentially returns true/false if its been locked to a version. We return this whenever its v.x.x.x. You would probably return whenever its not the default branch (whatever you have set in jenkins)

```
    /**
     * Wrapper for checking if loaded jenkins shared libs are pointing to a git branch or tag
     *
     * @return Boolean
     */
    Boolean isLockedSharedLibraryRevision() {
        List<Action> actions = $build().getActions(BuildData.class)

        return checkSharedLibraryBranches(actions)
    }

    /**
     * Check if shared libraries are locked to specific git tag (commit hash)
     * Return True if running on a particular revision (Git Tag)
     * Return False if running on HEAD of a branch (develop by default)
     *
     * Assumption is that Git Tag follows format vx.x.x (e.g. v1.0.22)
     *
     * @param actions (List of jenkins actions thatmatch BuildData.class)
     * @return Boolean
     */
    Boolean checkSharedLibraryBranches(List<Action> actions) {
        Boolean isLockedSharedLibraryRevision = false
        Boolean jenkinsSharedFound = false
        if (actions == null || actions.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Build actions must be provided")
        }
        // Check each BuildData Action returned for one containing the jenkins-shared revisions
        actions.each { action ->
            HashSet remoteURLs = action.getRemoteUrls()
            remoteURLs.each { url ->
                if ( url.contains('<insert-your-repo-name>') ) {
                    jenkinsSharedFound = true
                    Pattern versionRegex = ~/^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
                    /**
                     * When jenkins-shared is found evaluate revision branch/tag name.
                     * getLastBuiltRevision() returns the current executions build. This was functionally tested.
                     * If a newer build runs and completes before the current job, the value is not changed.
                     * i.e. Build 303 starts and is in progress, build 304 starts and finishes.
                     * Build 303 calls getLastBuiltRevision() which returns job 303 (not 304)
                     */
                    Revision revision = action.getLastBuiltRevision()
                    /**
                     * This is always a collection of 1, even when multiple tags exist against the same sha1 in git
                     * It is always the tag/branch your looking at and doesn't report any extras...
                     * Despite this we loop to be safe
                     */
                    Collection<Branch> branches = revision.getBranches()
                    branches.each { branch ->
                        String name = branch.getName()
                        if (name ==~ versionRegex) {
                            println "INFO: Jenkins-shared locked to version ${name}"
                            isLockedSharedLibraryRevision = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!jenkinsSharedFound) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("None of the related build actions have a remoteURL pointing to Jenkins Shared, aborting")
        }

        println "INFO: isLockedSharedLibraryRevision == ${isLockedSharedLibraryRevision}"
        return isLockedSharedLibraryRevision
    }
```